# "Deviate" Meanings

Tags: ambiguity

I have a question about the usage of the verb "*deviate*".  According to dictionaries, "*deviate from"* means:

> "to do something different from what is usual or expected"
>   "to be something different from what is usual or expected"

Suppose some "*original plan*" includes participant giving a speech according to a "prepared text":

1. > He deviated from the original plan.
2. > He deviated from the prepared text.

It seems that the two "*deviated*"s have very different meanings.  In sentence 1, "*deviated*" could mean either giving a speech different from the prepared text, or not giving speech at all.  In sentence 2, "*deviated*" could only mean just giving a speech different from the prepared text.

Comment: Admittedly I'm not a native speaker, but I think you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I suppose you could say that the word has two different meanings in these sentences, in the sense that it does not necessarily apply to two different things in the same way.

But you could say that about almost any word. Exactly how a word applies in any given context depends on the context.

A very similar example would be:

> 1. He changed the plan.
> 2. He changed his speech.

Or:

> 1. Al loves his wife.
> 2. Al loves apple pie.
> 3. Al loves woodworking.

In all three sentences, "loves" means something like "has a strong affection for". But clearly the details of what "love" means in the three cases would be quite different. I don't suppose that Al wants to literally eat his wife -- I hope not anyway. I don't suppose that Al wants to take an apple pie for a romantic walk on the beach and hug and kiss it -- I hope not anyway.

Or:

> 1. Bob looks old.
> 2. That building looks old.

In the first sentence you probably mean that he has gray hair and is skin is wrinkly. But the building probably does not have gray hair and wrinkly skin.

Etc etc. The EXACT actions that a verb indicates, or the exact appearance or behavior that an adjective indicates, will often vary with the context. I wouldn't say that this means the word is being used with two different definitions, just in two different contexts.

That's one of the amazing things about human language: That we routinely use a certain amount of abstraction without a second thought. I can say that I am "working on a speech" and that I am "working on my car's brakes" and that I am "working on my diet". The kind of work I am doing in each case is very different. But we have no problem calling all three things "work" and understanding what we mean when we say such things.